# ASP .NET MVC 3 - Passing Parameters from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, binding, view, model, model-binding

If you pass an anonymous object back to the controller, it populates controller arguments by looking at the anonymous object property names - so how would I pass back properties of related objects to my model so that the default value binder can bind them?

For example:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyItem MyItem { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

In the view, I want to pass the MyItem.Name back, how is this possible?  I have tried:

```
@Html.ActionLinke("Index", "MyController", new { name = "example" })
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLinke("Index", "MyController", new { myItem_Name = "example" })
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to create a custom ModelBinder and ModelBinderProvider.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "MyController", new { name = @Model.MyItem.Name })
```

And in the action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it that way but I thought the default model binder could handle inheritance so all I would have to have as a parameter is my view model object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following overload:

```
@Html.ActionLink( 
    "link text",                             // linkText
    "Index",                                 // actionName
    "MyController",                          // controllerName
    new RouteValueDictionary {               // routeData
        { "MyItem.Name", "example" } 
    }, 
    null                                     // htmlAttributes
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding 'the passing of object from view to controller'.
It's not that you're passing object - you're just rendering a link (anchor tag) in the page. The request will actually come from the browser when the user clicks the link. There is no 'server-side object passing' going on.

The link has to contain all the parameters you need on the server side (in controller) as query string parameters.

I think that what you really want to do is either:

1. render a form and submit it, or
2. pass only the id of the data you need and in the controller retrieve it (from DB for example)